# SMTP client using BouncyCastle's lightweight TLS API

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle

I need to add TLS support to a simple Java-based SMTP client. The client implements the SMTP protocol over java.net.Socket, i.e. it does not use Java Mail or other high level APIs.

I would like to use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)'s lightweight TLS API for this task. I have been looking for examples but haven't been able to find too much. Can anyone give any pointers?

Comment: Why? Why not use JSSE? It's been built-in for 10 years.

Comment: This runs on embedded hardware on which JSSE is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this was much easier than I expected. I could establish a secure SSL connection to a SMTP mail server by just modifying the original SMTP client code from this:

```
Socket s = new Socket(server, port);
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
InputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
[...]
```

To this:

```
Socket s = new Socket(server, port);
TlsProtocolHandler handler = new TlsProtocolHandler(s.getInputStream(),
                                                    s.getOutputStream());
handler.connect(new AlwaysValidVerifyer());
InputStream is = handler.getInputStream();
InputStream os = handler.getOutputStream();
[...]
```

The server's certificate is not being verified yet (`AlwaysValidVerifier` is a dummy verifier that will accept anything) but this is a good start already.

Comment: I have to go this way way as well, with c# version of the library.  
  
The handshake phase goes ok and I'm able to access the cert but after that I cannot properly send/receive http messages through this secure connection. Have you encountered any problems with it?  
  
I'm trying to use the stream provided by the handler along with a DataWriter/DataReader but always getting a timeout when doing 'await' on its async operation..  
  
Do you have any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: No idea, sorry. The above worked for me for SMTP+TLS, never tried HTTP.